# MacBook Pro 2015 won't turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I got a 13" 2015 MacBook Pro 13 and today it turned off because I didn't have the charger with me. Now when I plug the charger and try to turn on, it shows an almost empty battery and a lightning bolt below and won't turn on. Also, the charger LED is off.

- I checked the pins and are ok and everything is clean.
- When I disconnect the charger it shows a plug icon next to the lightning bolt, so the charger is getting recognized.
- I don't have any other MacBook to check if it's my MacBook or the charger

What could it be?

[image]

Comment: Close the screen and let it charge for a few hours. Report back.

Comment: If the charger never lights up then either the charger or the Mac itself are not working properly. Try another charger if you have access to one or take it to an Apple store (or independent repair shop) and see if they can charge it with a known good charger.